# How to use gstreamer to play gif file on windows

Tags: gstreamer, gif, animated-gif, gstreamer-1.0

As title,
I use this commend to play gif on windows, but it just show the first frame then close it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=demo.gif ! gdkpixbufdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I want to play whole gif file, is some gst element or parameter I forget to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gstreamer 1.14, user can use element of libav library to create gif pipline.
This is the sample commend.

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=demo.gif ! avdemux_gif ! avdec_gif ! autovideosink`